# How can I play an iPad video at reduced speed?

Tags: ios, ipad, video

For example, for YouTube videos, you can reduce or speed up the video. I have some videos saved on my iPad, and I'd like to be able to play it at a reduced speed.

Is there an innate way to do this on the iPad? I have an iPad Pro 6th generation with the latest iOS.

Comment: There is no speed adjustment natively. For that, you need a 3rd party app